# virtualbox cannot find vm of other user‘s vm in ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I created sersral virtual machines in virtualbox using root user,but when I changed to another user,the virtualbox cannot find the previous vm, how could I solve this problem?I tried to change the authority of related files to be 777,but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the users ~/.VirtualBox/ directory.

Open a terminal and enter:

```
cp -r /home/[USERWITHCORRECTVIRTUALBOX]/.VirtualBox  /home/[OTHERUSER]/
```

There might be access problems...

An alternative way is to create new machines and just import the hard disk image in these machines.

Comment: I have tried this way,but it doesn't work!Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Import and export machines is just to make a file with all the configuration of that. You can take that file and create a replica for the first one.
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf

Comment: I have concerned about this way,but it will take a lot of time because of there are so many vm to be created.um...I have no idea about this and have to use the this alternative way or importing after exporting.Any way, thank you very much for your suggestion  ^_^!!